# Java, generics and iterators

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to understand why I'm getting this error:

-- This is the error --

`File: ...\HashTable.java  [line: 103]
Error: The return type is incompatible with HashTableInterface<Key,Value>.iterators()`

The interface contains an innerclass:

`public class Entry<Key, Value>{...}`

and LinkedList is a similar to the java API yet it contains an iterator innerclass, but when testing out something more simple like:

-- This is working code, at least in drjava's interaction pane --

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
Iterator<String> test = list.iterator();
```

yet I cannot get this method to compile inside of my HashTable class:

-- This is the code I cannot get to work --

```
public Iterator<Entry<Key, Value>> iterator(){
LinkedList<Entry<Key, Value>> iter = new LinkedList<Entry<Key, Value>>();
return iter.iterator();
}
```

I assume its something simple, it doesn't seem too complicated, but any input would be greatly appreciated.

** You're right sorry about that it was supposed to list.iterator();

**Edits**

-- Alright here's the interface --

```
import nhUtilities.containers2.*;

interface HashTableInterface<Key, Value> {

    public boolean isEmpty();

    public Value get(Key key);

    public void add(Key key, Value value);

    public void remove(Key key);

    public void clear();

    public Iterator<Entry<Key, Value>> iterator();

    public interface Entry<Key, Value> {

        public Key getKey();

        public Value getValue();

        public void setValue(Value value);

    }
}
```

-- this is the implemented entry which is an innerclass of HashTable where the method that is broken resides--

```
public class Entry<Key, Value> {
    private Key k;
    private Value v;

    public Entry(Key key, Value value) {
        k = key;
        v = value;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a key of pair;
     */

    public Key getKey() {
        return this.k;
    }

    /**
     * Returns value of pair;
     */

    public Value getValue() {
        return this.v;
    }
}
```

**Edit+**

So i just realized

`public class LinkedList<Element> extends AbstractList<Element>`

and

`public abstract class AbstractList<Element> implements List<Element>`

and

`public interface List<Element> extends java.lang.Iterable<Element>`

yet inside of LinkedList there is

`private class Iterator extends AbstractIterator<Element> 
    implements nhUtilities.containers2.Iterator<Element>`

perhaps perhaps that is causing the conflict (because the LinkedList i'm using is not the java API LinkedList)?

Comment: You're question is not clear enough. What interface are you exactly describing? The last code seems incomplete. If you could maybe post the whole class (or maybe the class, the full method in the context of the class) and explain you're findings this might help understand the question better an answer you faster.

Comment: Iterator is not a List, so you can't write Iterator<String> test = list; 
Iterator<String> test = list.iterator(); is fine .

Comment: Please post `HashTableInterface<Key,Value>` - then I can expand my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`List` is **not an** `Iterator`. `List` **has an** `Iterator`. `List implements Iterable`.

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
Iterator<String> test = list.iterator();
                             //^^ here - you call iterator()
```

You need to call `iterator()` on a `List` to get an `Iterator` instance.

So you method should read

```
public Iterator<Entry> iterator(){
    List<Entry> iter = new LinkedList<Entry>();
    return iter.iterator();
}
```

Make sure you call `iterator()` on the `List`.

Make sure that your class `implements Iterable<Entry>`, as the generic type parameter on the `Iterable` interface is echoed in the `interface` method.

**EDIT**

From the OP's posted class it looks like a confusion between `Entry` in your `interface` and `Entry` in `iterator()` method.

Your `Entry` class is generic in `<K,V>` and your method is not generic at all.

So your interface requires that your `iterator` method returns a raw `Entry` or `Entry<?,?>` from the `iterator` method.

Presumably your implementation class implements an `Entry<K,V>` and returns an `Iterator<Entry<K,V>>` in its implementation of the method.

This is not compatible with contract in your `interface`.

Your `interface` method should be:

```
Iterator<Entry<Key,Value>> iterator();
```

More generally:

1. Your `interface` should extend `Iterable<Entry<K,V>>` rather than add your own custom method, this allows you to use the enhanced for-each-loop.
2. By style conventions we use single letters for generic type parameters, so `HashTableInterface<K,V>`
3. Don't use `public` in your `interface` - `interface` methods are `public` by default so this just adds noise.

So, your `interface` needs to be split into two and you end up with:

```
public interface Entry<K, V> {

    K getKey();

    V getValue();

    void setValue(V value);
}

public interface HashTableInterface<K, V> extends Iterable<Entry<K, V>> {

    boolean isEmpty();

    V get(K key);

    void add(K key, V value);

    void remove(K key);

    void clear();
}
```

**EDIT MK2**

A `List<Entry<K, V>>` is **not the same** as a `List<TableEntry<K, V>>`.

It's as I suspected at first, you (confusingly) have two `Entry` classes, one nested in the `interface` and one nested in the implementation.

So in your case `List<Entry<K, V>>` is not the same as `List<Entry<K, V>>`. See where the confusion comes in?

Your `List` is of the implementation `Entry` and your `interface` requires an `Entry` of the `interface` type.

And similarly your `Iterator<Entry..` that the method returns is of the wrong `Entry` type. Hence the compiler complains that your implementation does not implement your `Interface`.

Here is an example that works;

```
class HashTable<K, V> implements HashTableInterface<K, V> {

    private class TableEntry<K, V> implements Entry<K, V> {
    }
    private final List<Entry<K, V>> entries = new LinkedList<>();

    @Override
    public Iterator<Entry<K, V>> iterator() {
        return entries.iterator();
    }
}
```

Notice that if I change the `List` to `List<TableEntry<K, V>>` the code will not compile.

The take away point for you here is **never call classes the same thing** even if this seems like a really good idea.

Comment: I think that's what OP does, isn't it? That's the last part of the code that was provided, and it says it doesn't compile.

Comment: The first example doesn't. I am unsure which is the _real_ code.

Comment: public Iterator<Entry<Key, Value>> iterator(){
    LinkedList<Entry<Key, Value>> iter = 
new LinkedList<Entry<Key, Value>>();

return iter.iterator()
}

Comment: Haha ok, you're gunna love this, I changed it all back, I originally had everything with <Entry<Key, Value>> but I'm still getting the same error... \HashTable.java  [line: 103]
Error: The return type is incompatible with HashTableInterface<Key,Value>.iterator() I'll redit my Question

Comment: @MontyCsquared you'll have to show your implementation then - there's only so much I can guess... Maybe cut down your posted `interface` to only the required method then post the `class` declaration from you implementation and the `iterator()` method. And also your `Entry` method - I suspect you have generic type confusion and inner class type shadowing.

Comment: ...i tried it out, splitting it into two interfaces, but doesn't work... lemme think about it for a minute, maybe there's something I forgot to mention

Comment: I'm going to post my HashTable, I suspect it might be in how I implement entry...

Comment: ooooooooooooooooooooooooo I seeee said the fool

Comment: I understand...I havn't used a lot of inner classes before, so it never occurred to me, but it is obvious now that it should act just like a regular class, at least in implementing an interface, and yes I agree that the names are confusing, but I have a pretty clear idea in my head, it just never occurred to me that the compiler wasn't automatically implementing the entry since I told it to at the top of the class =) ... but ok I'm going to change the names

Comment: No problem, generics can be a little confusing, and combined with an `interface` with a nested `interface`... Please accept the answer if it answered your question.